# fastlane [!] Malformed version number string fastlane 2.39.2

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm newbe in Fastlane and for now I managed to login my AppleID and iTunesConnect so far, but still when I'm executing `fastlane provision` or any other lane I created in Fastlane file, i receive long message with 1 red line:

```
[!] Malformed version number string fastlane 2.39.2 (ArgumentError)
```

the full message looks like that:

```
[15:46:41]: -------------------------------------------------
[15:46:41]: --- Step: Verifying required fastlane version ---
[15:46:41]: -------------------------------------------------

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/new
Run `fastlane env` to append the fastlane environment to your issue
/Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb:207:in `initialize': [!] Malformed version number string fastlane 2.39.2 (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb:199:in `new'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb:199:in `new'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/fastlane_version.rb:10:in `run'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:252:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:50:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:230:in `block in execute_action'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:226:in `chdir'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:226:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:148:in `trigger_action_by_name'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:146:in `method_missing'
    from Fastfile:3:in `parsing_binding'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:54:in `eval'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:54:in `block in parse'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:43:in `chdir'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:43:in `parse'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:33:in `initialize'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:12:in `new'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:12:in `cruise_lane'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:30:in `handle'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.4/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.4/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.4/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.4/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:39:in `run!'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.4/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:303:in `run'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:42:in `start'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:66:in `take_off'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.39.2/bin/fastlane:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/bin/fastlane:22:in `load'
    from /Users/yoni/.fastlane/bin/bundle/bin/fastlane:22:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas what's the problem ?

Edit: thanks for repliers, I add my Fastfile:

```
# This is the minimum version number required.
# Update this, if you use features of a newer version
fastlane_version "fastlane 2.39.2"

default_platform :ios

platform :ios do

  # 1
  desc "Creating a code signing certificate and provisioning profile"
  # 2
  lane :provision do
    # 3
    produce(
      app_name: 'mZone Poker',
      language: 'English',
      app_version: '1.0',
      sku: '123abc'
    )
    # 4
    cert
    # 5
    sigh(force: true) #other: sigh(adhoc: true) \ sigh(development: true)
  end

  desc "Create ipa"
    lane :build do
      increment_build_number
      gym
    end

  error do |lane, exception|
  # This block is called if there was an error running a lane.
  end

end
```

Comment: You'll have to share your Fastfile for us to be able to help you with this issue.

Comment: Make sure to use `fastlane_version "2.39.2"` and have the number be surrounded by "

Comment: you're right, my line was 
fastlane_version "fastlane 2.39.2" 
instead of:
fastlane_version "2.39.2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As KrauseFx answered, I wrote `fastlane_version "fastlane 2.39.2"` instead of `fastlane_version "2.39.2"`